# Tell Selenium web driver to keep clicking "next" button until it can't

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pagination

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(1,20):
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    token_holders = token_holders + soup.find_all('tr')
    del token_holders[50*i]
    time.sleep(5)
```

I want the webdriver to keep clicking "Next" until it can't rather than me entering the amount of times it should be clicked in the for loop, but I'm not sure how I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `for` loop with `while` loop as follows:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    token_holders = token_holders + soup.find_all('tr')
    del token_holders[50*i]
    time.sleep(5)
```

This should allow you click `"Next"` button while it's possible or stop in case no button found on page